# How can I make my app run as a background process

Tags: java, android, process

I want to make my app run in the background like a process that runs always.

I need it because I want to get locations update for GPS every 2 minutes (longitude, latitude) and to use the information in a method.

For that I need for the app to be running when the phone is asleep or not in the UI of the app in other words I need the app will run always.

I'm sure that there is a way to make it , thanks anyway for any answers :)

Comment: If you are planning on getting location update every two minutes, I believe that the battery will run out in two hours...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html but Andro is right.  Every 2 minutes is not a good idea.  I would uninstall your app in less than that.

Comment: I agree, if you don't want to drain the user's battery you should choose a longer update interval. To make your app long live in background you can create a Service in it, search something like "android long running service" you can find many discussions.

Comment: what? i know that gps applications , updates the phone location every single second , and its much more code from what i want to do.
EDIT: the application is for me not for other users XD

Comment: Whatever. Service is the answer to your question.

Comment: @ mydDeveler The battery drain from an app is not determined by how many lines of code it took to write it. Put your GPS maps navigator on in teh car without plugging in and see how long your battery lasts. It drains the battery in any phone I've had quicker than the 12 volt charger in my car can recharge it

Answer (score 3):

This was just the first google search result I found:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

The answer here is to use a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), if this tutorial is lacking there are 6.4 billion others.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote your answer for the excessive use of hyperbole. :)

Comment: ha ha... ok, I'll reduce the number of possible google results :)

Comment: Exaggeration like that is the worst thing in the world. We've warned you a million times about this.

Answer (score 1):

We have something like this, but it is made up of several parts.

Firstly you will want your code to run (and be registered in the manifest) as a `Service`

You will probably also want to request `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` so that you can write and register a `BroadcastReceiver` that gets notified by `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` action and its `onReceive` method kicks off the service.

In our case we also have a front-end activity which also pokes the service to make sure it is running, but it's been a while snce I checked to see if this was still required.

Our service is nearly empty and `onCreate` immediately calls a custom `Handler` which then manages the 'ticks' which wakes the `Handler` and fires a `Runnable` if there is work to do, but this is where my code diverges from yours. In our case we only attempt to update the GPS location when the service 'ticks' (usually every minute) and there is work to do. It usually only performs a couple of dozen operations per client per day so I can't really advise on how it will impact battery usage.